# Read data from USB threw STM32

Tags: usb, stm32, communication, usb-drive, usb-hostcontroller

I want to read .txt file from Pendrive threw STM32. and send on RS232 port.

I found many circuit and code but I find read data from SD card but I cant find how to read pendrive.

Comment: USB host examples are supplied with the official libraries. `STM32Cube\Repository\\[Library name]\Projects\[Board name]\Applications\USB_Host\` Look in the EVAL boards, these are most richest.

Comment: USB host is very tricky and examples are very poor.